# JMeter - dynamic structure of HTTP request sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test, with JMeter, a HTTP request like that:

```
<v2:hotelAvailability>        
     <identification username='${username}' password='${password}'/>       
     <checkIn>${checkin}</checkIn>
     <checkOut>${checkout}</checkOut>
     <roomCriterias>
         <!-- one or more repetition -->                           
         <room adult="${adult}">                   
             <children> 
                   <!-- zero or more repetition -->              
                   <child age="${childAge}"/>
             </children>
         </room>                        
    </roomCriterias>
</v2:hotelAvailability>
```

As you can see, the structure of the request is dynamic: could be one room or more than one, could be one child or none. I would like to do something like this, but I don't know how to do it with JMeter:

```
<v2:hotelAvailability>        
     <identification username='${username}' password='${password}'/>       
     <checkIn>${checkin}</checkIn>
     <checkOut>${checkout}</checkOut>
     <roomCriterias>
         foreach(${room}:${roomsNb})                           
             <room adult="${room.adult}">                   
               <children> 
                   foreach(child:${children})              
                     <child age="${child.childAge}"/>
                   end foreach
               </children>
            </room> 
        end foreach                       
    </roomCriterias>
</v2:hotelAvailability>
```

I also want all variables, like ${checkin} or ${roomsNb}, to be read from a csv file. Is this possible?

More specific, if roomsNb=2 than the request will look like that:

```
 <v2:hotelAvailability>        
         <identification username='${username}' password='${password}'/>       
         <checkIn>${checkin}</checkIn>
         <checkOut>${checkout}</checkOut>
         <roomCriterias>                                           
                 <room adult="${adult}">                   
                   <children>                                  
                         <child age="${childAge}"/>                       
                   </children>
                </room> 
                <room adult="${adult}">                   
                   <children>                                  
                         <child age="${childAge}"/>                       
                   </children>
                </room>                                     
        </roomCriterias>
    </v2:hotelAvailability>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a solution for your problem.
Go though the below link and let me know if it suits you.

https://funwithjmeter.blogspot.com/2018/12/handle-dynamic-body-in-jmeter.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. Thank you !